# Why the trilinear GL_2 model is spherical?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, spherical-varieties

Consider the homogeneous space $X:=GL_2\times GL_2\times GL_2/ H$ where $H=GL_2$ is diagonally embedded into $GL_2\times GL_2\times GL_2$. My question is why $X$ is spherical (i.e., there is a Borel subgroup $B$ of $GL_2\times GL_2\times GL_2$ which has an open orbit on $X$).

Comment: Using the obvious Isomorphism to $GL_2\times GL_2$, you can rule that out by dimension count.

Comment: It is a calculation.  Your homogeneous space $X$ has dimension $12-4=8$. You should try to construct a Borel subgroup $B$ such that $B\cap H$ has dimension one. Since $B$ is of dimension $9$, you will see that the $B$-orbit $B\cdot 1H\subset G/H$ is of dimension 8, hence dense (and open).